# Geometric interpretation of autonomous differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am reading *Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications* by Carmen Chicone, and I am confused about the following paragraph about autonomous equations (page 8):

> Consider
> $$x' = f(x), \ \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}^n. \tag{1.7}$$
> The function given by $x \mapsto (x, f(x))$ defines a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ associated with the differential equation $(1.7)$. Here, the first component of the function specifies the base point and the second component specifies the vector at this base point. A solution $t \mapsto \phi(t)$ of $(1.7)$ has the property that its tangent vector at each time $t$ is given by
> $$(\phi(t), \phi'(t)) = (\phi(t), f(\phi(t))).$$
> In other words, if $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is on the orbit of this solution, then the tangent line to the orbit at $\xi$ is generated by the vector $(\xi, f(\xi)),$ as depicted in Figure $1.1$.
>
> [image]

My confusions are:

1. It says that the tangent vector at time $t$ of $\phi$ is $(\phi(t), \phi'(t))$. The tangent vector to what? The image (orbit) of $\phi$ lives in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but $(\phi(t), \phi'(t))$ lives in $\mathbb{R}^{2n},$ so it's not tangent to the image. The graph $(t, \phi(t))$ lives in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, so it cannot be tangent to the graph.
   To me, the tangent vector to the orbit is just $\phi'(t)$.
2. About the $\xi$ part. Again, $(\xi, f(\xi))$ lives in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, so I don't know to what this vector should be tangent.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the tangent vector to the solution at time $t_0$ is $\phi'(t_0)$ itself, and it just has its "tail" at $\phi(t_0)$.

Comment: Ohhh so we identify $(\phi(t), \phi'(t))$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a pair of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, drawn tip-to-tail? So the point of this paragraph is the rather obvious fact that the tangent vectors of a solution match up with the vector field $f(x)$?